# How do I change multiple file names in R

Tags: r, file

I want to change the name of different map files of the distribution of different species of plants.

Right now they have the full name of the species, like:

```
Amaranthus australis.kml
Capsicum annuum.kml
Cucurbita moschata.kml
Ipomoea alba.kml
Persea donnell-smithii.kml
```

And I wanted to name them, using the first 3 characters of each word, like this:

```
ama_aus.kml
cap_ann.kml
cuc_mos.kml
ipo_alb.kml
Per_don.kml
```

Does anyone know how to do this in R?

Comment: Do you want also a batch-file .BAT solution? If not, please remove the batch-file tag from your question. Thanks...

Comment: You probably want to check that your new names are unique.

Comment: Do you want to rename them in the directory?  If so [`file.rename`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/files.html) will be helpful combined with the solutions below.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I have applied them and I'm feeling close to the solution!

Answer (score 6):

This could be useful

```
Names <- c("Amaranthus australis.kml",
           "Capsicum annuum.kml",
           "Cucurbita moschata.kml",
           "Ipomoea alba.kml",
           "Persea donnell-smithii.kml")

sapply (lapply(strsplit(tolower(Names), " "), substr, 1, 3), 
        function(x) paste(paste(x[1], x[2], sep="_"),"kml", sep="."))
[1] "ama_aus.kml" "cap_ann.kml" "cuc_mos.kml" "ipo_alb.kml" "per_don.kml"
```

Comment: Hello Jiber, it works perfectly. I modify a little the script, because some of the names has more than 2 words, like Capsicum annum var. annum). 

Maybe is my fault, because I didn't asked the question properly, but I was hoping to use the resulting names as the names of each file of the directory.

How can I do that?

Sorry for the inconveniences, and for the bad english

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `paste` and `substr`

```
lines <- 'Amaranthus australis.kml
Capsicum annuum.kml
Cucurbita moschata.kml
Ipomoea alba.kml
Persea donnell-smithii.kml'

x <- read.table(text=lines, as.is=TRUE)

paste(tolower(substr(x[, 1], 1, 3)), 
      paste(substr(x[, 2], 1, 3), tools::file_ext(x[, 2]), sep="."),
      sep="_")
# [1] "ama_aus.kml" "cap_ann.kml" "cuc_mos.kml" "ipo_alb.kml" "per_don.kml"
```

**Edit:**  Here's a way to do it with regex, but I like the other way better because it seems like there would be fewer edge cases with it.

```
text <- strsplit(lines, "\n")[[1]]
tolower(sub("^(\\w{3})\\w* (\\w{3})[A-Za-z-]+\\.(kml)$", "\\1_\\2.\\3", text))
```